# como imprimir palavras com 7 ou mais de 7 letras no python

Tags: python

tenho que fazer um codigo que imprima nomes com mais de 7 letras
estou usando o pycharm
meu código esta o seguinte:

```
nome = input("Digite os nomes separados por vírgula: ")
nomes = nome.split(',')

def imprime_nome_com_7_letras(nomes):
    print("nomes com mais de 7 letras")
    print([nome for nome in nomes if len(nome) == 7])

imprime_nome_com_7_letras(nomes)
```

se alguem pode me ajudar obrigado.

Comment: Qual é a dúvida? O código que escreveu até faz sentido, o único detalhe é que está exibindo apenas nomes com EXATAMENTE sete letras, pois fez `len(nome) == 7`, mas não é isso que é pedido no enunciado.

Comment: O seu codigo recebe vai receber mais de um nome. O metodo `split()` retorna uma lista, onde cada item dessa lista é uma palavra.  Para você validar item por item de uma lista, `for nome in nomes:` pra checkar o tamanho da string `if len(nome) > 7: print(nome)`

Comment: Apesar da função não estar implementada de acordo com os padrões do Python, se você substituir `len(nome) == 7` por `len(nome) >= 7`, você já terá o resultado desejado. Contudo, sugiro estudar um pouco mais sobre as estruturas de funções.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É so fazer um for para ir em cada nome e printá-lo se caso obedecer a regra, colocando um if dentro dele:

```
def imprime_nome_com_7_letras(nomes):
   print("nomes com mais de 7 letras")
   for nome in nomes:
    if(len(nome) >= 7):
        print(nome)
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(nomes))`, o ideal seria que evitasse esse tipo de laço para percorrer a lista. Melhor seria `for nome in nomes`.

Comment: Concordo, Woss. Faz um tempinho que não mexo com python e esqueço as vezes. Obrigado vou ajeitar!

Answer (score 0):

Se quer filtrar uma sequencia segundo um critério, use a função embutida `filter()` que segundo sua [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#filter):

> ***`filter(function, iterable)`***
> Constrói um iterador a partir dos elementos de iterable para os quais function retorna verdadeiro.
> *iterable* pode ser uma sequência, um contêiner que com suporte a
> iteração, ou um iterador.

```
nomes = "Alexandre,Eduardo,Henrique,Murilo,Theo,André,Enrico,Henry,Nathan,Thiago,Antônio,Enzo,Ian,Otávio,Thomas,Augusto,Erick,Isaac,Pietrp,Vicente,Letícia,Maya,Sara,Yasmin"
nomes = nomes.split(",")        
    
print(*filter(lambda nome: len(nome) >= 7, nomes), sep="\n" )
```

Resultando:

```
Alexandre
Eduardo
Henrique
Antônio
Augusto
Vicente
Letícia
```

<sup>Teste no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/SfLevu)</sup>